# How to use a variable as "value" attribute in <option> tag

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

I'm currently using Laravel and I want to have a dropdown box display category names from my database, but when selected the value it returns to the server should be a numerical value of the name selected which is also stored in the database.

Like so:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <option name="pid" value="$category->id" id="cname">{{$category->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

The values are passed from my Controller to the Blade template. As you can see, I want it to display the category names in the drop down (which it does fine), but once selected and submitted, I want the category ID to be returned. Since the "value" attribute returns the value, I want to have the variable `$category->id` as the "value". I want to do this without using JavaScript or jQuery. Only with PHP. How would I go about accomplishing this and is it even possible?

When I try to use `value="{{$category->id}}"` I get the Laravel error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'parent_id' cannot be null

So it seems like it isn't submitting the value of the dropdown.

Here is the code I'm currently using in my Blade template:

```
<form class="" action="{{route('createsubcategorypost')}}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cname">Sub-Category name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cname" value="" placeholder="Sub-Category Name" id="cname" class="form-control">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pid">Parent ID</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option name="pid" value="{{$category->id}}" id="pid">{{$category->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <center>
      <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success">Create Sub-Category</button>
    </center>
  </div>
{{csrf_field()}}
</form>
```

And this is the code in my Controller:

```
public function CreateSubCategoryPost(Request $request){
        if ($request->cname == null) {
          session()->flash('errormessage',' Invalid sub-category name.');
          return redirect()->back();
        }
        $scc = SubCategory::where('name',$request->cname)->first();
        if ($scc !== null) {
          session()->flash('errormessage',' Sub-category with that name already exists.');
          return redirect()->back();
        }
        $subCategory = new SubCategory;
        $subCategory->name = $request->cname;
        $subCategory->uniqueid = 'SCA'.str_random(28);
        $subCategory->slug = str_slug($request->cname,'-');
        $subCategory->parent_id = $request->pid;
        $subCategory->save();
        return redirect()->route('categories');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you you are displaying the category name inside the option tag :

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <option name="pid" value="{{$category->id}}" id="cname">{{$category->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I've actually tried it that way, however, when submitting the form I get the Laravel error: "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'parent_id' cannot be null". So it seems it isn't submitting the "$category->id" value (which is the parent ID of the subcategory). I've updated my original post with the code I'm currently using.

Comment: It is giving you that error because you need to give the <select> a name attribute, and it should be parent_id unless you are altering the name in PHP.

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed something so simple. That completely solved it. It's working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Everything you call from a database in Laravel should have the format `{{$category->someName}}` no matter where you place it in your view. In your case you need to enclose `$category->id` in `{{ }}`

Comment: I get the Laravel error: "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'parent_id' cannot be null". Please check my updated post with some more code details. Thanks.

Comment: This acquires data from the form to post to the db `$model_instance ->db_column = $request->input-name;`  This saves the data `$model_instance->save();`   This initializes the controller to pull data from the db `$model_instance = model_name::find($id);`   This tells the controller which view you want to use the data from the model  `return view('folder.show')->with('any_name', $model_instance);` And finally this is what you use within your view `{{ $any_name->db-column }}`   All in all, in your case - `{{ $subCategory->db-column }}`

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Turns out I simply needed to give the <select> a name attribute. Doh! Happy holidays :)